# What Type of Siding is this?

Tags: siding, rot

I know this is a dumb question, but I'm having trouble finding siding that looks like this.  I assume its wood given it is rotting near the roof, but I don't see any splinters.  Instead it is coming off in "flakes".  I would like to just replace a few pieces if I can find something similar, but honestly I'm not finding anything close.

Can someone steer me toward what style / material this is?  Thank you.

[image: Chimney Siding]

Comment: Looks exactly like an image of one style of "Hardiplank" fiber cement siding, though it might be another brand. Excess moisture from being too close to the roof may be causing it to deteriorate, but "rot" may not be quite accurate. I believe that stuff is brand-stamped up under the overlap, if you take a piece off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s James Hardie cement lap siding called: “Beaded CedarMill”.

You can see it here (scroll down about 3 pages)it even shows the bead on the board:

https://www.jameshardie.com/products/hardieplank-lap-siding?loc=refresh

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this stuff to me:

"James Hardie 8.25-in x 144-in-HZ5 HardiePlank Beaded Cedarmill Fiber Cement Lap Siding" (with the possible caveat that it might be a different width.)

Fibercement, "beaded" (the lower feature) fake wood grain (rather than "smooth" which is the other option.) None of the sites I looked at have a linkable image, so just search for that text and look at the images.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you very much!